# Close a newly opened window in PyQt4?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I need a command which can close the current window in PyQt using a `button.clicked.connect(function)`..the "function" should be able to quit the current window.I have used `self.close()` but it doesn't work.
 THIS SITE HAS BEEN HACKED

```
button.clicked.connect(self.function)

def function():
    #what shall I write here to close this window?
```

Comment: Please don't use links to code or screenshots of code - copy and paste the actual code into your question.

Comment: ekhumoro  have  a look..

Comment: You need to post a more realistic example. The code you've posted doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i just want a command which can close the current window in PyQt

Comment: self.close() doesn't work

Comment: @DhruvShah. Keep a reference to the window as an attribute. Then do `button.clicked.connect(self.mywindow.close)`.

Comment: QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit this is working..